# Customizing ItemWriter to work like CompositeWriter to write the to db and xml

Tags: spring-batch

designing batch to process xml file. 
XML will be read using StaxEvenItemReader and Input data will be validated in processor. Processor will return new 
Data without any validation errors will be persisted to database and data with validation error will be written to database different xml structure.
i have extended ItemWriter to customize the writing. i would like to know if this is good practice and will there by any technical challenges.

Here is the Job configuration

```
@Bean
    public StaxEventItemReader<CustomerRequest> xmlReader() {
        StaxEventItemReader<CustomerRequest> itemReader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
        fileName="customer.xml";
        FileSystemResource inputFile = new FileSystemResource(Paths.get(inputDirectory,fileName));
        itemReader.setResource(inputFile);
        itemReader.setStrict(true);
        itemReader.setFragmentRootElementName("customer");
        itemReader.setUnmarshaller(xmlReadMarshaller());
        return itemReader;
    }


    public Jaxb2Marshaller xmlReadMarshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller ();
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(CustomerRequest.class);
        return marshaller;
    }

    public Jaxb2Marshaller xmlWriteMarshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller ();
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(CustomerResponse.class);
        return marshaller;
    }


  @Bean    
  public CompositeWriter compositeCustomerWriter(CustomerItemWriter customerItemWriter,StaxEventItemWriter<CustomerResponse> customerStaxEventItemWriter) {
      CompositeWriter cw = new CompositeWriter();
      cw.setCustomerItemWriter(customerItemWriter);
      cw.setCustomerXmlWriter(customerStaxEventItemWriter);
      return cw;
  }

  @Bean
    public StaxEventItemWriter<CustomerResponse> customerStaxEventItemWriter() {
      StaxEventItemWriterBuilder<CustomerResponse> staxBuilder = new StaxEventItemWriterBuilder<>();
      FileSystemResource outputFile = new FileSystemResource(Paths.get(inputDirectory,"output.xml"));
      return staxBuilder.name("ResponseFile")
                        .rootTagName("CustomerResponse")
                        .marshaller(xmlWriteMarshaller())
                        .resource(outputFile)
                        .build();
    }

     @Bean
    public TaskletStep createCustomerStep(CustomerProcessor customerProcessor,CustomerItemWriter customerItemWriter,StaxEventItemWriter<CustomerResponse> customerStaxEventItemWriter) {
        CompositeWriter compositeInvoiceWriter = compositeInvoiceWriter(customerItemWriter,customerStaxEventItemWriter);
        return stepBuilderFactory.get(CREATE_INVOICE_STEP)
                                 .<CustomerRequest,CustomerData>chunk(100)
                                 .reader(xmlReader())
                                 .processor(customerProcessor)
                                 .writer(compositeCustomerWriter(customerItemWriter,customerStaxEventItemWriter))
                                 .stream(customerStaxEventItemWriter)
                                 .build();

    }


    public class CompositeWriter implements ItemWriter<CustomerData> {

    private ItemWriter<CustomerData> customerItemWriter;

    private StaxEventItemWriter<CustomerResponse> customerXmlWriter;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends CustomerData> items) throws Exception {
        customerItemWriter.write(items);             
        customerXmlWriter.write(convertToCustomerResponse(items)));       converting to different type and calling write n staxevenitem writer
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Data without any validation errors will be persisted to database and data with validation error will be written to database different xml structure.
>
> i would like to know if this is good practice

I would not use a composite ItemWriter in this case. "Bad data" can be skipped and a `SkipListener` would write it to a different location.

> and will there by any technical challenges.

There is no technical challenges but there is a functional "misinformation": With a composite ItemWriter, bad data will be included in the total item count which is misleading. However, with a `SkipListener`, you will have a separate counter (writeSkipCount) and you will be able to distinguish good data count from bad data count.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. i would like to explain my issue further with example. Lets say the batch is processing 50 records. Out of 50, 10 records are with bad data. In this case i need to write 40 records to database and all the 50 records to xml file as a response to file provider(whether record is processed or not). This is actual scenario which am trying to achieve using compositeWriter.